# How to convert a list of tuples to a matrix?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have the following list of tuples:

```
list = [(House, Dog, 7), (House, Cat, 5), (Garden, Dog, 4), (Garden, Cat, 3), (Park,Mouse,2)]
```

I am looking for a matrix with the following structure:

```
result = [
          ['' ,  Dog,  Cat, Mouse],
          [House,  7,    5,    ''],
          [Garden, 4,    3,    ''],
          [Park,  '',   '',    2 ]
         ]
```

Comment: Create a nested dictionary, filling it out each time you get a new value, and once you are done, convert it to a 2d array.

Comment: To be honest I am a beginner and dont know how to do it . Do you have maybe an example? or solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will maintain the order of column/row names and produce the requested solution:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

input = [('House', 'Dog', 7), ('House', 'Cat', 5), ('Garden', 'Dog', 4), ('Garden', 'Cat', 3), ('Park', 'Mouse', 2)]

column_names = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(item[1] for item in input))
row_names = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(item[0] for item in input))

result = [[''] * (len(column_names) + 1) for i in range(len(row_names) + 1)]

for i in range(len(column_names)):
    result[0][i+1] = column_names[i]

for i in range(len(row_names)):
    result[i+1][0] = row_names[i]

for item in input:
    result[row_names.index(item[0]) + 1][column_names.index(item[1]) + 1] = item[2]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

data = [("House", "Dog", 7), ("House", "Cat", 5), ("Garden", "Dog", 4), ("Garden", "Cat", 3), ("Park", "Mouse", 2)]

header = [""]
column = [""]
counts = Counter();

for place, animal, count in data:
    if animal not in header:
        header.append(animal)
    if place not in column:
        column.append(place)

    counts[(place, animal)] += count

result = [header]
for (place, animal), count in counts.items():
    col = header.index(animal)
    row = column.index(place)
    if row >= len(result):
        result.append([place] + [""] * (len(header) - 1))

    result[row][col] = count
```